# Send Email at a faster rate in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I had created an application to send Bulk Emails in ASP.NET.

You can check my these Articles on the same:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/send-bulk-mails-using-smtp-configuration-part-2/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/send-bulk-email-from-yahoo-and-hotmail-using-Asp-Net/

The problem is that these emails are taking a long time to get sent **nearly 800e mails in 1 hour**, I want these mails to go at a much faster rate. Could anyone help help me by showing any example or telling me what can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Once you hand over your packet to the mail engine, it's his job to send it. So I am not sure if we have any hand in doing anything at all afterwards unless of course you buy your own smtp server.

Comment: Off the top of my head you might want to try making the email sending method async so that the current thread isn't waiting on the response from that code. If my thinking is correct you'll be able to speed this up quite a bit.

Comment: @BlueIce, there are many legit reasons to need to send a lot of e-mail that is not spam. E-mail is still the primary way people get notified of important info in the applications they use and applications will often have thousands of users receiving notifications.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Agreed. I just wanted to give advice if legitimate uses  were not the purpose of this question. I wholeheartedly agree with you about other uses for bulk email.

Comment: Use asynchronous mail sending I have been sending and almost 1000+ mails at time.

Answer (score 4):

You can optimize your code to use async (best) or multiple threads (easier for some). You won't want to try to do too many at once as you can theoretically overload the smtp server. You can also look at using a different SMTP server that may provide faster performance, or setup a pool of SMTP servers and use many to send in parallel.

Another option is to use a more optimized third party component.  MailBee.NET says they are fast (no specifics though) and from the description certainly sound like they have a lot of optimizations. They support queued/pooled messages and can send messages directly (no SMTP server needed). Threaded code combined with direct message sending should be really fast.

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/smtp-component

You should be able to get far more than 800 messages per hour.  That's very slow.  Back when I used to program in ColdFusion (many years ago) I remember one of the main features in their 6.1 release was improved mail handling that in their tests was able to send [1.2 million messages per hour](http://www.adobe.com/eeurope/products/coldfusionmx61/whitepapers/pdf/6_1/cfmx61_performancebrief.pdf).

**NOT SPAM**

For those people who think bulk mail is only for spam, think about companies and organizations that have a lot of members who do want real mail. Even a small bank would easily have 10,000 customers. Send them each their monthly statement in a day and at 800 e-mails per hour, it'll take half a day just to send the mail.

In my particular case we run offer a product that includes an LMS for large universities. It's important for the notifications to be delivered quickly since many students will want to sign up for classes as soon as they get the notification that sign-ups are available. If we sent notifications to 2,000 students at 800 an hour, the people that happened to be first would have a huge advantage in course selection over the people who happened to be later in the list. That would not be acceptable.

I used to work for a large non-profit organization that had 4,000,000 members and we sent a monthly newsletter to members (not spam, subscribed newsletter). At that time we were using ColdFusion.

Comment: Thanks Samuel for answering my question. Could you please provide me any example or any link from where I can see that which other SMTP Servers can be used. I don't want to use third party component.

Comment: @AnubhavChaudhary, I don't know which SMTP servers are fastest, but there are a lot of options to research. https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=fastest+smtp+server Also turned up good blog post from MailChimp (spam) people: http://blog.mandrill.com/making-smtp-fast.html